# Repositioning image within div

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have HTML markup like this:

```css
body {
    background-color: #476CDA;
}


div.bla {
      margin: 15px 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;
}
div.bla img:first-of-type {   }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="bla">
    <h1>bla bla bla</h1>
    <p>again bla bla bla</p>
    <img src="http://goo.gl/Am3h3W" />
    <p>once more bla bla bla</p>
    <img src="http://goo.gl/ASwD62" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What should I put in `div.bla img:first-child` if I want the first img to be placed before the `h1` tag and act like a cover photo within the `div` (covered up all the width of that `division`, no margin)

if css positioning doesn't serve the purpose then JavaScript would also be acceptable.

OBVIOUSLY I CAN NOT CHANGE THE HTML PART.

Comment: can you reorder the html tags??

Comment: I am hoping the HTML part will be auto-generated so the first image can be after many `h1` `p` and `a` tags, thus I can't edit the html part. @Vishal

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.bla {
                margin: 15px 10px;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000000;
       }
            #img1 {
                width: 100%;
                height: 40%;
                margin: 0;
       }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="bla">
            <img id="img1" src="bla.png" />
                <h1>bla bla bla</h1>
                <p>again bla bla bla</p>
                <p>once more bla bla bla</p>
                <img src="blabla.png" />
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```